# Как методом ArrayList.remove() удалить конкретное число в Integer массиве?

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, syntax

Как методом ArrayList.remove() удалить конкретное число в Integer массиве?

Если в параметрах метода передать число без кавычек - будет означать индекс, в кавычках - не работает...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Circle {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            list.add(2);
            list.add(1);
            list.add(3);

            list.remove("2"); //что писать в скобках?

            System.out.println(list);


        }
    }
```

Comment: new Integer(2). Если вы передаете тип int , тогда удаляет по индексу. Если объект, то объект по equals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArrayList предоставляет два перегруженных метода remove ().

а. remove (int index) : Принять индекс объекта, который будет удален.

б. remove (Obejct obj) : принять объект, который будет удален.

То есть вам для удаления определенного значения нужно ввести это:
list.remove(new ТипArrayList(вашеЗначение)),
где ТипArrayList в вашем случае равно Integer, а вашеЗначение - ваше конкретное число